# Find the remainder when the 300-digit number 112222333333........ is divided by 8?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know i need to find the last 3 digits of the number and check its divisibility by 8.
But how do i find the last 3 digits here?

Comment: It's not clear. What happens after the run of $18$ 9s?

Comment: There will be **20** 10s , **22** 11s and so on.

Comment: Each of which takes more than one digit. The point is, there are two different possible conventions: one where multi-digit numbers overlap (which has a nicer formula) and one where they don't (which has a nicer-looking decimal expansion), and you haven't specified which one you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the scheme is to concatenate $2n$ copies of the integer $n$, starting with $n=1$ and continuing until we have $300$ digits. Thus, the $9$ one-digit integers account for

$$2+4+6+\ldots+18=2\sum_{k=1}^9k=90$$

digits. Each two-digit integer $n$ adds another $4n$ digits: it appears $2n$ times, and each appearance adds two digits. For instance, $n=10$ adds the string

$$\underbrace{1010\ldots1010}_{20\text{ copies of }10}$$

of $40$ digits. Thus, if we stop after adding the $2n$ copies of some two-digit integer $n$, we have a total of

$$90+\sum_{k=10}^n4k=90+4\sum_{k=10}^nk=90+4\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2-45\right)=2n(n+1)-90$$

digits. Do we reach $300$ digits while $n$ is still a two-digit number?

Clearly $2n(n+1)-90\ge 300$ if and only if $n(n+1)\ge 195$, and

$$13\cdot14=182<195<210=14\cdot15\;,$$

so the answer is *yes*: $n=13$ gives us only $274$ digits, but $n=14$ gives us $330$ digits. From here you should have little difficulty determining the last three digits of your number.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. What is the smallest integer $n$ such that 
$$2\sum_{k=1}^9 k+4\sum_{k=10}^n k=90+2n(n+1)-180\geq 300?$$

P.S. The smallest integer is $n=14$, since for $n=13$, the left-hand side is 274, it follows that the remaining 26 digits are $13$ times 14. Therefore the last three digits are 414 and the remainder is $414 \pmod{8}=6$.